# What happens to a process when the filesystem is full

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, signals

What happens to a process if the filesystem is full? Does the kernel send us a signal to shutdown and if so what signal is it. Obviously, a program will probably crash if it writes to the file system but I'm curious as to how this occurs (in gory kernel/operating system detail).

Comment: What does "fills up" mean? And why is a program going to crash hard when that happens?

Comment: Processes ain't files. If a process doesn't open any file, it can live happily ever after with a full disk.

Comment: I suggest you edit your original post, and be more definitive about what you're trying to do and what behaviour are seeing.

Comment: Your question makes more sense if you replace all `filesystem` by `memory`.

Answer (score 3):

> What happens to a process if the filesystem fills up?

Operations that would require additional disk space on the full partition (like creating or appending to a file) fail with an `errno` of `ENOSPC`.

No signal is sent, as a full filesystem is not a critical condition which makes a signal necessary. It's a routine, easily handled error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason a program should crash when the filesystem is full.  Obviously file writes will fail, but a well-written program should be able to cope with that - in C, this would mean that `fopen` returns `NULL` or `ferror` returns a non-zero value, etc.  I have encountered this many times, and some nasty things can happen such as overwriting a file with a blank version, but never a program crash.  If it does happen, it is presumably because the author of the program tried to use a `NULL` file descriptor or some similar problem, in which case the program would receive a `SIGSEGV` as usual.